# Find a commutative ring $R$ such that for a, b in R such that $a\neq b$ $a^n=b^n$ and $a^m=b^m$ where n and m are relatively prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers

Find an example of a commutative ring $R$ with unity such that $a$,$b$ $\in R$ , $a\neq b$, $a^n=b^n$, and $a^m=b^m$, where $n$ and $m$ are positive integers that are relatively prime.

This question is in Joseph Gallian's algebra book. I was preparing for a competitive exam; for that I was studying this book and trying to solve the exercises. For this question; I could only try the basic methods. I tried this on $i$, $Z_{n}$ where I took $n=8$ or $n=5$ but I could not find the numbers where the given conditions fit and so I could not find the suitable ring. Any hints would be appreciated. Please help.
P.S. I understand I am just a beginner. Please don't mind my lack of knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So $a^n = 0$ and $b^n = 0$ for all $a,b$ ? Are $n$ and $m$ fixed or do they depend on $a$ and $b$? Also, what happens when $a=0$ and $b=1$ ?

Comment: $n$ and $m$ are not fixed but they should be relatively prime. Yes, we can also take $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Comment: I still don't know what the question is, but I'm glad you got an answer you like.

Comment: Thanks. But if you want; I can explain the question.

Comment: That would be awesome, the title says for all $a,b$ but the answer consists of finding some $a,b$ so I'm very intrigued !

Comment: Actually, that's my mistake, sorry for that. correcting it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}_8$, $2^3 = 6^3 = 0$ and $2^2 = 6^2 = 4$

There are still more, $2^3 = 4^3$ and $2^5 = 4^5$, $4^3 = 6^3$ and $4^5 = 6^5$

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks a bunch for your time and for this stupid question of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example, which is not quite as nice but which uses a trick you might be able to take advantage of if you see a similar question: take the elements $x$ and $y$ in
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x, y]}{(x^2 - y^2, x^3 - y^3)}
$$
To show that $x \neq y$ in this ring, you have to show that $x - y \not\in (x^2 - y^2, x^3 - y^3)$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x, y]$. But this is true because every polynomial in that ideal has degree at least two.